# SharePoint 2013 Workflow get id of created item

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, workflow

I'm currently creating a basic workflow, which inserts a list item into another list. While configuring I have the option to specify an output variable, however I'm not able to get the ID of the newly created list item, I can only get the GUID.

[image]

After browsing I found out that I could use the REST API in combination with a workflow HTTP webservice call. However I'm wondering if any less complex solution is available?

Regards

Comment: Do you want the ID of the item that triggered the workflow or the item created by the workflow?

Answer (score 5):

You can lookup the list using the GUID of the new item created.

[image: Workflow]